# What will happen to a naked singularity during the Big Rip?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, space-expansion, dark-energy, singularities

I apologize in advance if some concepts I use are vague, but I am just an enthusiast.
I have read that the [Big Rip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip) will not rip off black holes because the event horizon will become equal to something else that I cannot remember. I understood that, even if I do not remember the word for the other horizon. But that assumed that black holes do not evaporate, correct? or the big rip somehow will prevent that? if not, once I have a  naked singularity, will it be ripped of by the dark energy field, or it will somehow become larger and become a wormhole.

Comment: @BenCrowell so the models assume that after that time the dark energy stops to expand space, or just that there is nothing left to rip (except perhaps, the black holes). In the last case the scale is not an issue because it eventually should happen (I might be wrong)

Comment: @julianfernandez A big rip is a singularity, where the scale factor diverges to infinity everywhere, so there's basically nothing to talk about in regards to "that moment" or what goes beyond.

Comment: @BenCrowell See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33386/55483 for an answer on rip versus black hole. In short, the horizons merge.

Comment: @BenCrowell I think op is under the impression that a black hole evaporates via hawking radiation into a naked singularity, and that it could do so before a big rip. In a big rip scenario there is almost certainly not enough time for it evaporate before the rip itself. But insofar as naked singularities are valid solutions to certain forms of GR the titular question remains valid and not obviously a duplicate.